# How do get a character count from innerText or InnerHTML using dojo?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, innerhtml

I have to use `Dojo` in my application and I am trying to get the total numbers with in an `HTML` element and I keep getting an error.

Here is my code:

```js
var attributeIcons = dojo.query(".attribute-icon");
if (attributeIcons.innerText.length = 4) {
  console.log(attributeIcons);
}
```

And I try to use this approach also:

```js
var attributeIcons = document.getElementsByClassName("attribute-icon").innerHTML.length;
console.log(attributeIcons);
```

Each approach gives me the same error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName("attribute-icon")` or `dojo.query(".attribute-icon")` returns array and you need to iterate over the array like this,

```
var attributeIcons = document.getElementsByClassName("attribute-icon");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(attributeIcons, function(el) {
    console.log(el.innerHTML.length);
});
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/wewanuxeqo/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 1):

Both dojo.query() and document.getElementsByClassName() return an array-like object. This means that you can't call .innerHTML on an array of nodes (you get undefined), and subsequently you can't call .length.

Check out these two references:
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/query.html, 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Try running the following to see your array.

```js
var attributeIcons = dojo.query(".attribute-icon");
console.log(attributeIcons)

// or 

var attributeIcons = document.getElementsByClassName("attribute-icon");
console.log(attributeIcons)
```

You can pick out one of the array items and then run .innerHTML.length on it, just not on the entire array.

```js
var attributeIcons = dojo.query(".attribute-icon");
console.log(attributeIcons[0].innerHTML.length)

// or 

var attributeIcons = document.getElementsByClassName("attribute-icon");
console.log(attributeIcons[0].innerHTML.length)
```

Hope that helps!